# Git - How to fetch or sync my working branch with origin

Tags: git, bitbucket

I am fairly new to Git/bitbucket and have a basic question. We have a  repository. The main/master branch is "develop". I have my branch created from this and cloned to this.
e.g. 
local folder C:\\branch

```
-- clone <project_db> 
$ git clone ssh://git@bitbucket.blah.com:port/<project>/repo.git

-- folder will be created now
$ cd <project_db>

-- create a new development branch now
$ git checkout -b <mybranch_develop>
Switched to a new branch '<mybranch_develop>'

-- just confirming
$ git checkout <mybranch_develop>
Already on <mybranch_develop>

-- push the new branch so it is available on bitbucket
$ git push origin <mybranch_develop>
```

SO now I have all the required files in C:\\branch\. I am doing my local development. Meanwhile the original "develop" branch have proceed and there are changes there (valid commits by other team members).

I have committed my changes to .

```
$ cd C:\<project>\branch\<project_db>

$ git checkout <mybranch_develop>

$ git commit -m "comment" 

$ git push origin <mybranch_develop>
```

Now, I don't care about my changes as some important changes have gone in main "develop" or origin branch and I want  to exactly same as "develop" or origin now. i.e. in sync with origin.
I am fine with my local changes being overwritten.

How to I do this?

I tried,

```
$ cd C:\<project>\branch\<project_db>

$ git fetch --prune
  OR
$ git fetch origin --prune
  OR
$ git reset --hard <mybranch_develop>
```

But nothing is helping. i.e. when I go to the local directory, it is still showing my changes.

I know since I know one file in origin or develop is exactly same name as mine in local ; but different contents. But I am seeing only my changes, not the one from develop.

What is it I am missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
$ git checkout develop
$ git pull origin develop
```

Comment: Thanks. Just wanted to be sure...
"develop" is the parent or main branch. So what does above command(s) do?
i.e.
$ git checkout develop ----> is it safe (I don't want anything in develop branch to change).
$ git pull origin develop ----> what exactly this pull command will do? 

The branch which I am working on is <mybranch_develop>.

I am really new (using perforce earlier) so just wanted to be safe.